# Wrap element to a new div

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
var searchInput = '<md-input-container md-theme-watch="true" flex><label for="sampletext1">Champ texte</label><input name="sampletext1" type="text" class="ng-tree-search"></md-input-container>';
element.before($compile(searchInput)(scope))
    .prev()
    .on('keyup', function (ev) {
        if (to) {
            clearTimeout(to);
        }
        to = setTimeout(function () {
            tree.jstree(true).search(ev.target.value);
        }, 250);
    });
```

I want to wrap `element` to a div: `<div class="nrh-tree-search-container"></div>` and the other element I created using `before` to the same div as the first child so it will look like this:

```
<div class="nrh-tree-search-container">
   <md-input-container md-theme-watch="true" flex><label for="sampletext1">Champ texte</label><input name="sampletext1" type="text" class="ng-tree-search"></md-input-container>
<!-- element should be added here -->
</div>
```

I tried as following :

```
var searchInput = '<md-input-container md-theme-watch="true" flex><label for="sampletext1">Champ texte</label><input name="sampletext1" type="text" class="ng-tree-search"></md-input-container>';
var searchForm = element.before($compile(searchInput)(scope))
    .prev()
    .on('keyup', function (ev) {
        if (to) {
            clearTimeout(to);
        }
        to = setTimeout(function () {
            tree.jstree(true).search(ev.target.value);
        }, 250);
    });
searchForm.wrap($compile('<div class="nrh-tree-search-container"></div>')(scope));
```

but this doesn't work I get `element` outside the `'<div class="nrh-tree-search-container"></div>'`.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/vwmHF/121/

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this:

Check the [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) method:

```
$('.accordionTrigger p').wrapAll('<div class="moreInfo"></div>');
```

The wrapAll() method will wrap all the elements matched into another element (compared to the .wrap() method which wraps the matched elements individually)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vwmHF/)**